# signtool revocation problem?

Tags: code-signing, certificate

I've got two binaries, one builded ~4 days after first, and signed with the same certificate (same Serial number, issued by Thawte), but, when I'm checking the certificate, on one there is error message `Revocation Status : The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.`
, the second works well. Is it possible, that the revocation server was offline at the time of signing, and that causes this problem? I'm not sure if there is other way how one certificate could have different revocation servers.

Another think I may think of is, that the second one was signed few days (< month) before certificate's expiration. Could this be the case?

Comment: How do you check the signature of your binaries?

Comment: r-click->properties->Digital Signatures->Details

Answer (score 1):

What format is the certificate in?  If you can get into a suitable format, you can use the "openssl" command line unix tool to investigate the certificate.  Openssl works on windows, too.

Here's a sample run:

```
openssl x509 -in usertrust.pem -inform PEM -noout -text
```

And here's the output:

```
Version: 3 (0x2)
Serial Number:
    07:74:8d:73:00:00:00:00:00:94
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
Issuer: C=US, ST=UT, L=Salt Lake City, O=The USERTRUST Network
Validity
    Not Before: Apr  5 18:35:06 2005 GMT
    Not After : Mar  6 03:22:04 2007 GMT
Subject:C=US, ST=UT, L=Salt Lake City, O=USERTRUST, CN=www.usertrust.com
Subject Public Key Info:
    Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
    RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
    Modulus (2048 bit):
        00:d7:21:6d:f8:58:e7:ed:52:5a:3e:fe:e5:bf:92:
        32:41:38:f1:ee:61:6f:da:6c:83:39:c8:b4:b1:fd:
        77:4a:35:a8:e8:3f:0b:bf:ff:2d:0b:b5:ed:56:80:
        d7:ca:89:c3:63:8b:a5:06:ed:b0:22:82:8d:a1:c6:
        ed:c8:d4:06:8d:be:d1:69:83:31:a7:13:2b:17:27:
        72:a4:85:97:55:fc:f7:ca:eb:c9:af:be:19:78:67:
        35:d1:7f:af:2d:3c:d3:86:c4:1e:fd:02:e4:ab:10:
        ea:d1:bb:63:19:fb:9a:61:ed:30:7e:88:0e:1a:1e:
        a7:a6:d5:8d:02:20:af:be:b0:0e:f5:30:44:e0:d5:
            b9:ab:b1:76:65:94:03:fc:c8:55:80:6d:a8:fa:b1:
        94:38:be:e2:78:45:8d:b5:7e:cf:e7:de:a1:09:46:
        a3:8b:ab:76:50:85:50:5d:58:91:78:21:a3:a2:dd:
        1d:c3:dc:0b:18:9d:fc:84:b2:17:f8:a7:48:e5:aa:
        c1:d3:43:83:49:ea:35:5f:e1:28:6c:33:a9:2f:ac:
        62:22:1d:6f:44:94:bb:09:be:7d:fd:c5:e4:fc:ff:
        92:4c:63:97:56:53:fe:77:5c:53:5b:ae:ab:7d:8b:
        af:74:ac:ea:30:80:b1:6e:08:57:85:01:7d:b4:3d:
        26:65
    Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
X509v3 extensions:
    X509v3 Key Usage: 
        Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment, Key Agreement
    X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
        TLS Web Server Authentication
    X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
        A0:3C:DC:84:FF:51:06:AC:C6:CB:21:EB:CB:05:07:D7:10:C2:68:E6
    X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
        keyid:75:01:28:97:C6:46:1B:34:6E:E8:A0:91:15:71:92:79:EE:B7:03:CE
        serial:15:6C:27:1A:54:FE:B3:82:BE:AF:54:FE:F4:A2:8B    
    X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
        CA:FALSE
    X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 
        URI:http://crl.usertrust.com/USERTRUST-ServerAuthentication.crl
        URI:http://www.utnsecurity.com/USERTRUST-ServerAuthentication.crl
    X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
        Policy: 1.2.840.114015.1.1
          CPS: http://www.usertrust.com/CPS
          User Notice: Explicit Text: ...

Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    cf:66:95:18:8b:a3:73:e7:04:a8:fa:16:f3:62:60:4a:26:f1:
    b5:37:b3:cd:7a:d4:9d:63:3f:a1:ee:52:30:29:9e:7a:b2:e7:
    ba:a0:f9:bf:4f:95:63:63:bb:a9:cf:c5:b9:18:bd:6a:e5:82:
    cd:3a:bf:37:ea:9c:57:bc:d8:20:d8:be:1a:8c:f5:00:9e:ad:
    c4:66:d3:60:92:dd:22:66:61:88:49:0c:05:72:05:03:9d:82:
    78:2f:9e:9c:f3:8b:d7:96:b7:8b:4b:6c:40:0f:7a:cb:f9:77:
    88:13:f7:74:f0:e7:31:2e:94:81:b9:d4:0a:7c:d1:1d:f3:8b:
    4c:e7:ae:21:12:40:f9:6a:1f:7d:a8:96:dc:90:11:6a:44:d7:
    fc:f5:98:a3:5b:bc:4f:51:ab:db:84:64:ad:69:e6:82:bd:d9:
    65:7a:44:43:65:8b:69:a7:01:8c:94:0d:4b:c3:be:29:ef:81:
    a9:80:0c:33:46:d7:37:be:4c:9a:e0:bb:3f:15:9e:dd:ef:f4:
    7f:70:e9:0b:5f:e3:18:a7:a4:80:8b:e1:ac:1c:46:33:e7:90:
    02:11:43:61:15:4e:97:ea:c2:24:84:58:31:a8:37:b4:84:bf:
    c0:70:a0:95:f9:64:c9:d2:94:86:5c:21:5d:51:b3:c6:b0:f4:
    02:cb:77:24
```

In particular, notice these:

```
X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 
    URI:http://crl.usertrust.com/USERTRUST-ServerAuthentication.crl
    URI:http://www.utnsecurity.com/USERTRUST-ServerAuthentication.crl
```

Those are the CRL's (for this particular certificate), and you can visit them with a regular browser to see what the problem is!  Note:  some certificates use OCSP for revocation instead, so look for OCSP and CRL in the output.

Answer (score 0):

First off you should check the MSDN documentation about how to validate signed binaries [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc700843.aspx#XSLTsection131121120120).  The error responce will be much more informative.

This [blogger has a workaround](http://khurramullah.blogspot.com/2008/08/certificate-services-unable-to-start.html), and if your having issues with the revokation server for your own keys, you will know if it's been revoked :).  Also, as this key is expired now it may not be a big deal to configure this setting.

If you post the detailed error codes I can look at it a bit more but this should work for you for now.

Answer (score 0):

Certificate signing is not dependent on checking for certificate revocation, only verification is.  This sounds like there was a temporary network glitch when you were verifying the certificates.  Is this problem repeatable?